# Read specific Bits from bitstring.BitArray

Tags: python

I have a Bitarray and want to read from a certain position to another position.
I have the int variable length in a for loop, so for example I have:

`length = 2`
and my Bitarray looks something like:

```
msgstr = bitstring.BitArray(0b11110011001111110)
```

I then want to read the first two bits and convert them into an int, so that I have:
`id == 3`
And for the next round when length has changed in value it should start from the third bit etc.

```
id = bitstring.BitArray()
m = 0
while 5 != m:
   /////////////
   Length changes in value part of Code
   /////////////
   x = 0
   if m == 0:
       while length != x:
           id.append = msgstr[x] #msgstr is the BitArray that needs to be read
           x = x + 1
   m = m + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is called slicing.

```
for i in range(0,len(msgstr),length):
    print msgstr[i:i+length].uint
```

This code will get you what you are asking for.  It will take the first two bits and convert them into an int, then will take the third and fourth bits and convert them to an int, etc.